# Can someone assess my original thermostat's wiring setup?

Tags: wiring, thermostat, nest

This is a new world for me, I haven't messed with circuits since physics 101. When I watched a quick youtube tutorial on setting up my Nest E, I thought it'd be a simple "move wire in old C, to new C in Nest."

But I'm looking at my old thermostat and the instructions said if you have a Rc and Rh thats coupled = dual transformer and not compatible for Nest E. That plus I don't have a wire for W1 (or maybe its broken off??) instead just a wire in W2. Which subsequent instructions stated that W2/O/B should go into the *O/B slot on the Nest. But I doubt that means to put both W2 and O wires into the *O/B slot on the Nest...

Really need some guidance on a dummies explanation for what to do. I was half tempted to just move forward and put wires in best I could, but physics101 warned me not to mess with electricity and improper connections. Some more context, just moved into the apartment. I believe its central Heating and AC. [image: wiring of old thermostat]

[image: Old thermostat]

**Old thermostat
[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at your air-handler/furnace please?

Comment: Also post the model number and the manual. In the manual it usually tells you which ones to put it in. You did well by taking a picture first.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel sorry whats the air-handler/furnace? If thats wiring located on the furnace itself, I won't be able to access it since only maintenace has the keys. I posted a picture, would that be where the wiring is located?

Comment: @diyuser did you mean the model# for the old thermostat? (Braeburn, 1220NC)
Nest is a T4000ES

Comment: I'm talking about the wiring on the furnace itself...since you're in an apartment, is there a reason you can't get maintenance to do your bidding for you BTW?

Comment: The thermostat appears to use normal color coding but we really need to know the other end or incorrectly Connecting your new thermostat may be the end result.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel not a problem, it just takes a bit, with the pandemic maintenance has been moving a bit more slowly and only really responding to emergency conerns. I'll follow-up after i get back with them

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I contacted maintenance, like I thought theyre really only meeting for emergencies and said itd be a while b4 someone could get to me. So while waiting i walked around the apartment and ended up finding the electric meter, but no furnace. So i looked around my unit, opening up panels lol and happen to find a circuit diagram dunno if this may be what you're looking for.